# Remove old chrome remote from macbook

Tags: google-chrome

I want to remove the last two application links. These two apps are old chrome remote links, each for a different user. Unable to delete with a long press. There is no remote application in the app folder.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an app in the chrome app folder.

1. Right-click the app and open the app in finder.
2. Delete it.